# How to activate links for a row when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, html

Update and Delete links are for each row in the table. I want the links of each row to be activated when I click the checkbox for that particular row. Does anyone know how to do it?

I added the `{{forloop.counter}}` and now it is generating a new id but all the ids are still linked to the links of the first row. Each row has its own links and those links need to be activated when I click the checkbox for that row.

```js
function toggleLink(checkBox) {
  var link1 = document.getElementById("agreeLink1");
  var link2 = document.getElementById("agreeLink2");
  var link3 = document.getElementById("agreeLink3");
  if (checkBox.checked) {
    link1.style.display = "inline";
    link2.style.display = "inline";
    link3.style.display = "inline";
  } else {
    link1.style.display = "none";
    link2.style.display = "none";
    link3.style.display = "none";
  }
}

<!-- language: lang-html -->
{% for catalog in object_list %} 
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <form>
                <p><input type="checkbox" id="agreeCheckbox{{forloop.counter}}" name="agreeCheckbox" value="{{catalog.id}}" onchange="toggleLink(this);"></p>
              </form>
            </td>
            <td>{{ catalog.DatasetName }}</td>
            <td>{{ catalog.Type }}</td>
            <td>{{ catalog.Classification }}</td>
            <td>{{ catalog.OriginalSource }}</td>
            <td>{{ catalog.OriginalOwner }}</td>
            <td>{{ catalog.YearOfOrigin }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>


    <div class="card-footer text-center text-muted">
      <a href="{% url 'catalog_edit' catalog.pk %}" id="agreeLink1" style="display:none;">Update</a> |
      <a href="{% url 'catalog_delete' catalog.pk %}" id="agreeLink2" style="display:none;">Delete</a> |
      <a href="{% url 'export_to_xml' %}" id="agreeLink3" style="display:none;">Export to XML</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: As you can see, code in comments is absolutely unreadable. Please use the `edit` button under your question if you want to add more information to it. I've done it for you in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try, add onclick and assign link to "thisLink" variable like this;

```
  <tr onclick="thisLink= {{catalog.link}}">
    <td>{{ catalog.DatasetName }}</td>
    <td>{{ catalog.Type }}</td>
    <td>{{ catalog.Classification }}</td>
    <td>{{ catalog.OriginalSource }}</td>
    <td>{{ catalog.OriginalOwner }}</td>
    <td>{{ catalog.YearOfOrigin }}</td>
  </tr>
```